# How to validate request with hashed value for exist on table column?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.6

I have hashed user name in my table. How I can use this validation method for hashed values:

```
'name' => 'required|unique:users'
```

Example request with user name: **John**

Exist user name example on table: **RndqMUU5ZUJnQ2JhWjZvNUh5ZGp2UT09**

I think first I must hash input value from request and after validate am I right? Where I can hash and validate this values?

Comment: How was the name hashed in the first place?

Comment: John @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Comment: I mean how did you hash the name 'John'. What method or Hashing function did you use?

Comment: I have my own hashing method for `encrypt/decrypt` data @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the encrypt function?

Comment: No, I can't show your my encrypt method! @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Comment: I do not intend to expose your hashing algorithm, my question is to find out if you compare by string value i.e `namehash === dbnamehash` or it uses other techniques that doesn't do hash result comparison so I can recommend a method that may help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `check` method of the [Hash facade](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Hash.html), from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules):

> ```php
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
>
> // some code
>
> if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedElement)) {
>     // The elements match...
> }
> ```

Now, you can use this in a [Custom Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules):

#### 1. Creating Rule class

```php
php artisan make:rule HashedNameCheck
```

#### 2. Customize class

**app\Rules\HashedNameCheck.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; // <-- notice.

class HashedNameCheck implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // here you get the hashed name stored in your database (?)
        $hashedName = App\User::find(1)->name;

        // next, you compare this with the received value.
        return Hash::check($value, $hashedName);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute does not match with the stored value.';
    }
}
```

#### 3. Apply the rule.

Use this in your controller:

```php
$request->validate([
    // some other validation rules..
    'name' => ['required', 'unique:users', new HashedNameCheck],
]);
```

or in your custom [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation) class:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // some other validation rules..
        'name' => ['required','unique:users', new HashedNameCheck],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Seems your rules strings/array is broken

Comment: @HCK If I want to validate the same field using other rules then I always need to create several rules for several files?

Comment: @Otabek if those rules are custom and you want them to be reusable, yes. Although if you know that all those rules will be applied just in this case  you could include all those rules in just one file (notice that the `passed` method returns a boolean, so just implement your logic in that method and return the result of your validations).

Comment: Can you show with example how to write all other my own rules to one file and use it? @HCK

Comment: For example In my database every values hashed with my own method and if I want rehash and check to exist that values I must create for each field single rul file? @HCK

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no built-in validation rule that first hashes the value.

You can always write a custom rule:

```
$rules = [
   'name' => [ 
        'required', 
        function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (User::find(Hash::make($value))) {
               return $fail('The username already exists');
            }
        },
];
```

You can also move this rule outside if you use it often, e.g. you can add it in your service provider:

```
 public function boot() {
    Validator::extend('uniqueHashedUser', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        if (User::find(Hash::make($value))) {
           return false;
        }
       return true;
    });
 }
```

Then you can just use it as:

```
 $rules = [ "name" => 'required|uniqueHashedUser' ];
```

Comment: How I can use first your code on example [form request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests) `rules()` method? @apokryfos

Comment: Make that array and then `return $rules;` in the rules function

Comment: See to [my form request](https://repl.it/@OtabiekMansurov/Form-Request) and say me please where I have an error? @apokryfos

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a closure to validation and then you can check hashed value.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => [
        'required',
        'max:255',
        function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (Hash::check($attribute) === $value) {
                return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi all here something to consider on setting up you storage driver

1. The Local Storage is not Public altho you can symlink to get access to it this is ot recommended for public items like avatars
2. The Public driver: will work best for public items

Take note and this is important:
Your APP_URL in env must be set to the url you are using, so if you have something like mysite.test you must have this as your APP_URL

Hope this help anyone